# Reservation schema querying cars available within dates

Tags: sql, database, database-design

I'm trying to practice on database design and querying. Given the UseCase: I select a start date and end date, then it will pull down available cars within the set date range. This is my schema:
[image]

This is my pseudo code:

```
SELECT vehicle_id FROM reservation WHERE pickup_date AND end_date IS NOT between given start date and end date
```

Comment: show some sample data and the expected result as formatted text.

Comment: @vkp please check my pseudo code

Comment: pseudo code doesn't help either..it is unclear what you need.

Comment: @vkp i want to select the vehicle_id from reservation WHERE the pick_up date and end_date is not within my start_date and end_date... Let's say start_date is 2017/5/15 end_date is 2017/5/20

Comment: Just an FYI... you are selecting from a table that has past, present and future reservations. What if a vehicle has never been reserved, ie. a new vehicle added to the company? Your select will not get that vehicle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the information provided, you can use

```
select vehicle_id
from reservation
where not (pickup_date<='2017-05-20' and end_date>='2017-05-15')
```

Comment: could you also help mie with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43942415/sql-best-way-to-iterate-through-returned-results