# SQL best way to iterate through returned results

Tags: mysql, sql, database, relational-database

I am trying to practice my SQL skills, I have this schema:

[image]

And i came up with this query:

```
SELECT vehicle_id 
FROM reservation 
WHERE NOT (pickup_date<='2017-05-20' 
AND end_date>='2017-05-15')
```

it will return rows of vehicle_ids, I want to be able to use those vehicle ids and return vehicle_name from vehicle table. How to go about this? I have heard of SQL joins will a JOIN achieve this goal?

Comment: Hint:  `JOIN` the tables together.

Comment: Yes, a JOIN is what you want.

Comment: Also be careful working with dates. If that is a datetime, then your date isn't 2017-05-15; it's 2017-05-15 00:00:00.000... depending on the datatype of the field. So 2017-05-15 12:55:55.555 might be unintentionally missed. Also, if dealing with decimal seconds, be wary of the precision of the datatype. In some cases, 2017-05-15 23.59.59.999 can be interpreted the same as 2017-05-16 00:00:00.000.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure of what you ask for, but if you want one query to return both the vehicle ids and the vehicle names, you should do this :

```
SELECT r.vehicle_id, v.vehicle_name
FROM reservation r
LEFT JOIN vehicle v ON r.vehicle_id = v.vehicle_id
WHERE NOT (r.pickup_date<='2017-05-20'
AND r.end_date>='2017-05-15')
```

This will return two columns : one of vehicle ids, and one of vehicle names.

(sorry for the french word 'vehicule')

Comment: NOTE: Please don't use comma syntax for JOINs. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/894490/sql-left-join-vs-multiple-tables-on-from-line

Comment: Or, re anti-comma arguments being specious: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25957600/3404097.